# Unix Cat : No such file or directory error

Tags: shell, unix

I have the following script

```
#!/bin/bash
set i=0;
while read line
do
  echo "$line";
  $i < cat "my.log" | grep -w '$line' | wc -l;
  echo "$i";
  i=0;
done < "test.txt"
```

`test.txt` has values like

```
abc
def
lmn
```

my log has values like

```
> INFO 2013-08-16 13:46:48,660 Index=abc insertTotal=11  
> INFO 2013-08-16 13:46:48,660 Index=abcd insertTotal=11  
> INFO 2013-08-16 13:46:48,660 Index=def insertTotal=11  
> INFO 2013-08-16 13:46:48,660 Index=abcfe insertTotal=11
```

The goal is to pick each value from the `test.txt` and to search for that pattern in the `my.log` file.

The number of times the pattern is found is assigned to the variable `i`.

I am going to check the value of `i` and if it is `0` or the pattern was not found then I want that pattern to be stored in another file.

Currently, I am getting

```
./parser.sh: line 7: cat: No such file or directory
```

I have tried the cat command on the command line and it has worked fine but it is giving this error from within the script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to use a file called `cat` as input to a command called `0`. That won't work.

Instead of

```
$i < cat "my.log" | grep -w "$line" | wc -l;
```

do this:

```
i=$(cat "my.log" | grep -w "$line" | wc -l)
```

See the question [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) for a discussion of quotes and http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html for a description of command substitution in bash.

Comment: Thanks @Tichodroma. That worked although I didn't get the expected result. The value of my variable was still 0 even though I know that the file has 1 occurence of the pattern.

Comment: Why do you use the `-w` option of grep? It means 'Select  only  those  lines  containing matches that form whole words.' Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, so basically I have values like abcd abc abcde on different lines. I want to pick the lines where the search pattern (for example : abc) matches the value exactly.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a real sample of both files.

Comment: Done. please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Brilliant. It works. Could you please explain the solution or point me to a link.

Comment: Thank you @Tichodroma. If i could give you bonus points,I would :-)

Comment: Using a docker container, this doesn't work for me. I copy-pasted the following line 
i=$(cat "my.log" | grep -w "$line" | wc -l)
and got
cat: my.log: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

I had error messages like:

```
cat: command not found
curl: command not found
```

It was caused by code like this:

```
export PATH=$1
export SERVER=$(cat s_remote)

curl $@ $SERVER$PATH
```

And the solution was to rename the PATH variable to something else. PATH is used locally by the shell, and setting it for a different purpose interferes with the shell.